# FB.ui share how to open in page instead of popup

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share, fb.ui

Trying to set up a sharing mechanism with FB.ui.
The issue is the share dialog opens a popup instead of it opening in the same page.
The reason I'm trying to avoid the popup is that safari doesn't show the popup in mobile.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js',
                    dataType: 'script',
                    cache: true,
                    success:function(script, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        FB.init({
                            appId            : 'someID',
                            autoLogAppEvents : true,
                            xfbml            : true,
                            version          : 'v3.0'
                        });

                        share();
                    }
                });
        });

        function share() {


            FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'share',
                    href: 'https://example.com',
                    quote: 'Some description',
                    title : 'Title',
                    hashtag: null,
                    display: 'iframe'
                },
                response => {
                    window.parent.postMessage(
                        {
                            earningRule: 'fb_share',
                            action: 'shared',
                            response: response
                        }
                    );
                }
            )
        }
    </script>
```

Is there any way to either avoid the popup or to address the safari popup blocking issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are trying to open the dialog in the callback function of an AJAX request. You must use `FB.ui` directly on mouse interaction, or it will get blocked by browsers.

If that does not work, you can use sharer.php instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/sharing/share-dialog/?locale=de_DE#sharedialogvialink